# MYSQL: use multiple order by in mysql server

Tags: mysql

i want run mysql query to do:
first get threads order by 'olaviat' desc
then get thread order by time_update desc
i type this code:

```
select * 
from groups_thread 
where group_id = $groupid 
order by olaviat,time_update desc 
limit $limit,36"
```

but this code run order by time_update desc and show olaviat in last of anythings

olaviat is number - time_update is number too

so anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't write anything in a order by, it defaults to `ASC` (ascending order). You have to specify `order by olaviat desc` to sort it in descending order:

```
select * 
from groups_thread 
where group_id = $groupid 
order by olaviat desc,time_update desc 
limit $limit,36
```

Comment: Yes ! its Work thank you and sorry i dont have rep for give u vote

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
select * 
from groups_thread 
where group_id = $groupid 
order by olaviat desc,time_update desc 
limit $limit,36
```

You need to specify the sorting order for `olaviat` as be default it takes it as **ASCENDING**